# Composition of Polynomials and Galois Theory

Tags: galois-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, with Galois group isomorphic to the symmetric
group $S_n$. How do I show that $f$ cannot be expressed as a composition $g(h(x))$ of two polynomials $g$ and $h$
of degrees > 1.

Thanks

Comment: A Google search on "composition polynomials galois" returned the article http://www.ccms.or.kr/data/pdfpaper/jcms22_3/22_3_497.pdf as one of the top hits (did you try an internet search before asking your question?) and the paragraph after Lemma 3.2 will be of interest to you.